# how to sort a csv file by two columns in python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file that contains 6 columns.

I want to sort it by col #2 and then by col #3.

My current code is creating a blank file:

```
import csv
with open('original.csv', mode='rt') as f, open('sorted.csv', 'w') as final:
        writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        _ = next(reader)
        sorted1 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
        sorted2 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[2]))
        for row in sorted2:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One point: "If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference." https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @sancho.s That is certainly true for Python 2, but in Python 3 CSV files _must_ be opened in text mode. This is rather annoying when you want to process CSV files with code that runs on both Python 2 & Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring - True. OP does not specify version, then the caveat.

Comment: Did you check the contents of sorted1 and sorted2 to ascertain where is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that your output file is empty is because

```
sorted2 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[2]))
```

is trying to sort the data from `reader`, but you've already read all the data in the previous sorting statement, so there's nothing left for the reader to read. However, you really *don't* want to re-sort the data from `reader`, you want to re-sort the data in `sorted1`, like this:

```
import csv

with open('original.csv', mode='rt') as f, open('sorted.csv', 'w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    _ = next(reader)
    sorted1 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
    sorted2 = sorted(sorted1, key=lambda row: int(row[2]))
    for row in sorted2:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

OTOH, there's no need to do the sorting in two passes. You can do it in a single pass by changing the key function.

```
import csv

with open('original.csv', mode='rt') as f, open('sorted.csv', 'w') as final:
    writer = csv.writer(final, delimiter='\t')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    _ = next(reader)
    sorted2 = sorted(reader, key=lambda row: (int(row[1]), int(row[2])))        
    for row in sorted2:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

That key function first compares items by their `row[1]` values, and if those values are identical it then compares them by their `row[2]` values. That *may* not give the ordering that you actually want. You may want to reverse the order of those tests:

```
key=lambda row: (int(row[2]), int(row[1]))
```

As Peter Wood mentions in the comments, Writer objects have a [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method that will write all the rows in one call. This is more efficient than writing the rows one by one in a `for` loop.

BTW, there's no need to do this assignment:

```
_ = next(reader)
```

I guess it makes it clear that you're discarding the 1st row, but you could just write the call without performing an assignment:

```
next(reader)
```

Comment: Also, [**`writerows`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) will loop and write all the rows for you.

Answer (score 3):

With pandas you could achieve simple.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('original.csv', delimiter='\t')

df = df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'], ascending=[True, True]) # parameter ascending is applied to 'col1' and 'col2' respectively.

df.to_csv('sorted.csv')
```

[doc to pandas read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)


[doc to pandas sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html)

Comment: That's nice, but the OP hasn't mentioned Pandas, so why are you posting a Pandas answer? Not everyone has Pandas installed, and the standard `csv` module is quite capable of performing a simple task like this.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function can return a tuple

```
sorted(reader, key=lambda row: (int(row[1]), int(row[2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 with open('original.csv',mode='r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
        sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda row:(int(row[1]), int(row[2])))
```